# Jquery webservice call Cannot read property 'contentDocument' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sending this valid json response from the backend

```
[
    {
        "id": 123,
        "vendorName": "PoppyCounter",
        "item": "Chocltae"
    },
    {
        "id": 1234,
        "vendorName": "PoppyCounter",
        "item": "Chocltae"
    },
    {
        "id": 12345,
        "vendorName": "PoppyCounter",
        "item": "Chocltae"
    }
]
```

I am making a webservice call from Jquery as shown below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://192.168.2.46:8086/Poller/poll/initial',
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (msg) {

            },
            error: function (e) {
                $("#divResult").html("WebSerivce unreachable");
            }
        });
    });



    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divResult" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the following exception

TypeError {stack: (...), message: "Cannot read property 'contentDocument' of undefined"}

Could anybody please tell me how to resolve this error ??

Comment: Is it that your ajax request wants `jsonP`, but you only return `json`?

Comment: Thank you very much ,How can i return jsonp ??

Comment: Do you have to use `jsonp` at all? If website and service are on the same domain `json` will do it. How you return `jsonP` depends on what you are using on the back-end/server. PHP, Rails, ...? Not a back-end person so can't help you that much, sorry. If you are on different domains, you could also look into activating `CORS` to allow that ajax request in `json`.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for JSONP but the response from your backend is raw JSON, the response should be more like:

```
jsonCallback([
  {
    "id": 123,
    "vendorName": "PoppyCounter",
    "item": "Chocltae"
  }
])
```

There should also be a global function called `jsonCallback` that will get the data array as an argument.

```
function jsonCallback (data) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

You have to setup the backend to format the JSONP, you can find the correct callback name as jQuery will send "jsonCallback" as the GET parameter "callback".

The backend should then serve the request as `application/javascript` instead of `application/json`.